# New Method is not working

Tags: java, function, methods

I'm getting an error that

> "Illegal start of expression and error ';' expected"

I don't know if I'm doing the new method right, so please help me I need this for school work.

```
public class Testing{
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{

    String un, pw, login;
    final String Username = "javajava";
    final String Password = "testing";

    BufferedReader inpt = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    public void Login(){
    System.out.println("Please enter your Username & Password for you to be able to use the program");
    System.out.println("Warning! Case Sensitive!");

        for(int trial=3; trial>=1; trial--){
            System.out.print("Username: ");
            un = inpt.readLine();

            System.out.print("Password: ");
            pw = inpt.readLine();

            System.out.println();
            if(un.equals(Username) && pw.equals(Password)){
                System.out.println("User has successfully logged in!");
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Sorry, you've entered an incorrect Username/Password - (" + (trial-1) + ") retries left");
            }
            if  (trial==1){
                System.out.println("It seems that you've reached the limit for the login attempts, please try again later");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where are you trying to declare the method?!

Comment: What do you mean?
I'm new to method statement and I don't know how to start it or something..

Comment: Could you provide a line number?

Comment: You should use indentation for methods as well.

Answer (score 6):

You can't<sup>[1]</sup> have a method inside a method.

Move

`public void Login(){`

To outside

`public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{`.

I advise you to go through the tutorial [**Defining Methods**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html).

---

<sup>[1]</sup> You can, indirectly, have a "method inside a method". It is possible to have a method that contains an *inner class*, and that class will contain a method. So.. you actually get a method inside a method ;)

Comment: +1. You could have a method inside a class that is inside a method :P

Comment: @Eng.Fouad `class Test {Test() {test();}void test() {new Test() {void test() {new Test() {void test() {new Test() {void test() {new Test() {void test() {new Test() {void test() {new Test() {void test() {new Test() {void test() {new Test() {void test() {new Test() {void test() {new Test() {void test() {new Test() {void test() {new Test() {void test() {new Test() {void test() {new Test() {void test() {new Test() {void test() {new Test() {void test() {new Test() {void test() {new Test() {void test(){System.out.println("Hooray for nesting");}};}};}};}};}};}};}};}};}};}};}};}};}};}};}};}};}};}};}}`

Comment: @Alowaniak If you do this in real life, you'll have no friends.

Comment: It's advise not advice.

Comment: @jimjim Thanks, English is my 3rd language :)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
import java.io.*;

public class Testing {

    static String un, pw, login;
    static final String Username = "javajava";
    static final String Password = "testing";

    public static void Login() throws IOException {
        System.out
                .println("Please enter your Username & Password for you to be able to use the program");
        System.out.println("Warning! Case Sensitive!");
        BufferedReader inpt = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                System.in));
        for (int trial = 3; trial >= 1; trial--) {
            System.out.print("Username: ");
            un = inpt.readLine();

            System.out.print("Password: ");
            pw = inpt.readLine();

            System.out.println();
            if (un.equals(Username) && pw.equals(Password)) {
                System.out.println("User has successfully logged in!");
                break;
            } else {
                System.out
                        .println("Sorry, you've entered an incorrect Username/Password - ("
                                + (trial - 1) + ") retries left");
            }
            if (trial == 1) {
                System.out
                        .println("It seems that you've reached the limit for the login attempts, please try again later");
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        Login();
    }
}
```

Comment: Care to explain, why OP should try that?? and first letter should be capital always :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your method outside your main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {...}
public static void Login() {...}
```